# Problem about destructor function called immediately

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I am learning c++ and having hard time on this exercise of my internet course. It takes data from user through constructer and print it. However, the destructor function is called immediately after every time i enter value.

```
class employee{
    private:
        int no;
        char *name;
        char *position;
        float time;
    public:
        employee();
        employee(int a, char *n, char *m, float x);
        ~employee();
        //setter
        void setNo(int);
        void setName(char*);
        void setPos(char*);
        void setTime(float);
        //getter
        int getNo();
        char* getName();
        char* getPos();
        float getTime();
        
};

void employee::setNo(int a){
        no = a;
    }
    void employee::setName(char* a){
        delete name;
        name = new char[strlen(a) + 1];
        strcpy(name, a);
    }
        
    void employee::setPos(char* a){
        delete position;
        position = new char[strlen(a) + 1];
        strcpy(position, a);
    }
        
    void employee::setTime(float a){
        if(a > 0 && a > 150){
            cout<<"Enter valid time! (The restriction range is between 0 to 150.)"<<endl;
            exit(0);
        }
        else{
            time = a;
        }
    }
    //getter
    int employee::getNo(){
        return no;
    }
    char* employee::getName(){
        return name;
    }
    char* employee::getPos(){
        return position;
    }
    float employee::getTime(){
        return time;
    }
//constructer
    employee::employee(){
        name = new char[1];
        position = new char[8];
        no = 0;
        strcpy(name, " ");
        strcpy(position, "employee");
        time;
    }
    employee::employee(int a, char *n, char *m, float x){
        name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
        position = new char[strlen(m) + 1];
        no = a;
        strcpy(name, n);
        strcpy(position, m);
        time = x;
    }
    employee::~employee(){
        cout<<"The object "<<position<<" "<<name<<" is deleted."<<endl;
        delete(name);
        delete(position);
    }
int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"The number of employees: ";
    cin>>n;
    
    employee *a = new employee;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int no;
        float time;
        char name[20], position[10];
        cout<<"Enter No: ";
        cin>>no;
        cout<<"Enter Name: ";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"Enter Position: ";
        cin>>position;
        cout<<"Enter Time: ";
        cin>>time;
        a[i] = employee(no, name, position, time);
    }
}
```

Maybe I am expecting something wrong. What i want is the destructor to be called and print msg about objects were deleted, after entering data all my datas. But the destructor is called right after the first employers data insertion, and same goes other employers.

Comment: Aside of the destructor problem, your program accesses out-of-range of arrays. You should use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of raw arrays.

Comment: Also, you have quite a mismatch between your `new` and `delete`. `new[]` must be released with `delete[]` and `new` must be released with `delete`. And you treat `a` as an array, when it's really a single object.

Comment: You're creating a temporary `employee` object to assign from.  That's the one being destroyed.

Comment: *and having hard time on this exercise of my internet course* -- Looks like your internet course is teaching you `C` and not `C++`.  Why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: ` employee *a = new employee;` creates one employee. The only valid index in `a[i]` is zero.

Comment: Got to wonder at the quality of your internet course if it is teaching you to code like this.

Comment: Replace `employee *a = new employee;` with `employee *a = new employee[n];` is one thing you should do (assuming you are unwilling to use a vector).